# Sulforaphane vs. Hyperthermic conditioning (sauna use) which would induce a greater heat shock response in the human body?

Tags: human-biology, human-physiology, health, medicinal-chemistry

I’m curious to know which would induce a greater upregulation of heat shock proteins, consuming sulforaphane or putting the body through heat stress such as using the sauna.

Sulforaphane reference- https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2975177/#!po=79.7872

Hyperthermic conditioning reference- 
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3418130/

There are many more articles/studies done on these two subjects, these are just 2 references of the many.

Comment: Could you please edit your post add the references you are referring to regarding the upregulation of heat shock proteins by sulforaphane? This might not be common knowledge. I addition, the answer to your question might depend on the concentration of sulforaphane and the temperature/humidity/duration of the sauna use.

Comment: Do the references added suffice for you?  @Arsak